# I can't use a function defined in another file, as if it wasn't there

Tags: python, function, jupyter-notebook, python-import

I'm creating a problem written un python in Jupyter notebook. I have a file named as "myfunctions1.py", where I have defined a function called ClearSky. In the very same directory I'm writing a new programe but it turns out that every time I try to use the name of the file as a module and I try to access the function I get an error.

```py
def ClearSky(csvfile):

    #Fem que obvie els tabuladors
    df = pandas.read_csv(csvfile, delimiter = "\\t")

    #Subsitueix els Nan per strings amb 000
    df.fillna("000", inplace=True)
    
    #Convertiré en un array tot el percal 
    NUBarray = df.to_numpy()
    
    #Creem la llista dels clear sky on anirem afegint els dies que toquen
    clearsky = []
    
    #Les úniques columnes no nules han de ser les de dia/mes/any
    #Que venen a ser la columna 0, 1 i 2, per això comencem per la columna 3 
    col = NUBarray.shape[1]
    row = NUBarray.shape[0]
    lastcol = col - 1
    
    #Fem dos bucles, el primer anirà fila a fia que és el dia, el segon anirà columna a columna
    #Per a tenir un dia clear sky les columnes han d'estar totes composades per 000
    for n in range(0,row):
        for k in range(3,col):
            #Trenco el primer bucle si trobem una columna diferent a '000'
            if NUBarray[n,k] != "000":
                break
                
            #Si no s'ha trencat fins la última columna i aquesta val '000'   
            #Afegim a la llista el dia, el més i l'any que són les columnes 0,1 i 2
            else:
                if k == lastcol:
                    clearsky.append(NUBarray[n,0])
                    clearsky.append(NUBarray[n,1])
                    clearsky.append(NUBarray[n,2])
                    
        #Aquesta part només afecta si hem trencat el primer bucle, li diem que vagi al següent dia 
        #Així no cal que mire totes les columnes, no ens interessa
        continue
                    
    #Me torna una llista però vull que sigue unarray de 3 columnes
    #Puc trobar el nombre de files dividint per tres 
    #Uso reshape per a canviar la dimensió
    clearskyrows = int(len(clearsky)/3)
    clearskyarray = array(clearsky)
    
    #Retorno un array amb els dies de cel clar
    return clearskyarray.reshape(clearskyrows,3)
```

What I do in another file:

```py
from  myfunctions1 import ClearSky
```

I'm getting the error:

```py
    ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)/var/folders/h3/_ws68mys35vfc_g11qml5cmr0000gn/T/ipykernel_10758/2584126548.py in <module>16 #Let's improt useful functions17 from numpy import array,reshape,stack---> 18 from  myfunctions1 import ClearSky

    ImportError: cannot import name 'ClearSky' from 'myfunctions1' (/Users/andreacerapalatsi/Practiquesempresa/myfunctions1.py)
```

Comment: If you try running that `import` command in a python interpreter or IDE, does it work?

Comment: @baileythegreen No, it doesn't work.  I have the function in one file and I'm importing the file with "from my functions import ClearSky" in another file from the same directory but I get the error you can see in the last line of the description. I use jupyer notebook.

Comment: I understand you are trying to use a Jupyter Notebook. I'm asking if you can try it in just a python interpreter, rather than a Jupyter Notebook. That would help diagnose whether the problem is with the file locations or something to do with the notebook environment.

Comment: @baileythegreen I've executed the function in an online python interpreter and when I try to import I have no problem. But with jupyter it recognises my document myfunctions1.py as a module but I can't import the function that I've defined inside.

Comment: Please try doing it in a python interpreter on your computer, with the exact same directories/files as your jupyter notebook is using. The point is to eliminate potential sources of difference, and using an online interpreter just introduces another one.